# Disproving a calculus statement

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

**Statement:**

> If $f'(a^+)$ and $f'(a^-)$ exist finitely at a point, then $f$ is continuous at $x=a$.

**My disproof:**

If $f(x)=\{x\}$ (fractional part function), then around $x=1$, $f(x)=x$ for $x<1$ and $f(x)=x-1$ for $x\geq1$. Either way, $f'(1^+)$ = $f'(1^-)=1$, *yet*  the function $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=1$.

---

I am a bit weak in calculus. Hence, I wish to know if my disproof is correct. Thank you!

Comment: Though I wonder if there should be a "disproof-verification" tag instead...

Comment: If $f'(1^-)$ means $\lim_{h\to 0^-} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}$ then that limit doesn't exist since $f(1) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,
$$ f'(a^+) = \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
f'(a^-) = \lim_{x\to a^-} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}. $$
We claim that if $f'(a^+)$ and $f'(a^-)$ both exist and are finite, then $f$ must be continuous.  To see this, first note that in order for these two limits to exist, $f(a)$ must be defined (and, implicitly, be finite).  Next, note that
$$ \lim_{x\to a^+} [f(x)-f(a)] = 0, $$
for, if not, then $f'(a^+)$ would not exist.  This implies that $f(a^+) = f(a)$.  Similarly, $f(a^-) = f(a)$.  But then we have
$$ f(a^-) = f(a) = f(a^+), $$
which implies that $f$ is continuous at $a$.

---

Now, to address what went wrong with your example:  let $f(x) = \{x\}$.  At $a=1$, we have
$$
f(1) = 0, \qquad
f(1^+) = 0,
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
f(1^-) = 1. $$
This causes no difficulty with $f'(1^+)$, since
$$ f'(1^+)
= \lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1}
= \lim_{x\to 1^+} \frac{(x-1) - 0}{x-1}
= 1. $$
On the other hand,
$$ f'(1^-)
= \lim_{x\to 1^-} \frac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1}
= \lim_{x\to 1^-} \frac{x - 0}{x-1}
= -\infty. $$
Thus the left-sided derivative does not exist, which means that your function fails to satisfy the hypothesis of the proposition.

Comment: I understood your detailed answer, thanks! :D But, I wonder what is wrong in my reasoning? What I did was to: /// break $f(x)$ into two parts: $x$ and $x-1$. I noted that $x$ has a finite RHD at $x=1$ while $x-1$ has a finite $LHD$ at $x=1$. Hence, both $f'(1^+)$ = $f'(1^-)=1$ exist, yet $f(x)$ is discontinuous. //// What is wrong here?

Comment: @GaurangTandon You don't have the existence of both of the one-sided derivatives.

Comment: Are one-sided derivatives not defined at all in calculus? Or is it just in my case that they happen to not exist?

Comment: @GaurangTandon I've edited the answer to address your question.